# How can I ignore the namespace in an XML document in c#?

Tags: c#, xml

I'm trying to open a XML file in c#, find a node by attribute name, which is working fine and then displaying the name of an XML attribute in the same node.

My code is simple (as I pinched it from other sources!) and works on my test XML doc. However, when I try it with an actual file it doesn't work. I've been pulling my hair out (not that I have much left) and have discovered it's because of the xmlns attribute in the actual files I'm using. The path to the namespace does not exist.

My code is as follows:

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load(@"c:\deroschedule\test.sym");
var orient = doc.SelectSingleNode("//Attr[@name='Orientation]/@value");
```

the above code works perfectly when xmlns is not included in the file. However, when xmlns is included the orient variable is null. The xmlns path doesn't exist, when i try to navigate to it in a browser I get a 404 error.

Not sure what a xml namespace is to be honest, but I have thousands of these files and can't manually edit them. Is there an easy way to get C# to overlook the namespace and just pretend it's not there? I've tried with Xpath, but that just blew my mind!

Comment: You shouldn't 'ignore' it but specify it in the query.

Comment: ok thanks, any hints on how to include it in the query?

Comment: Got a sample xml?

Comment: hi, sorry not sure how to attach. You can find the XML file here: http://www.dero.co.uk/dev/test6.sym it's a sym file, but is really XML

Comment: Ignoring the namespace is a bit like ignoring the first three characters of the name. It's not something you want to do. For the answer to the question, just search for "XPath default namespace" and take your pick from thousands of answers.

Comment: Hi, I've tried looking through the thousands of answers that you suggested but can't get any to work. Do you have any advice?

Comment: ok i think i'm getting somewhere albeit slowly. I need to declare the namespace? Does this have to match the xmlns in the xml file? Can I do this with the sample code I've posted with my question?

Answer (score 5):

Ok I figured it out for myself. Thought I would post the answer here even though there are thousands of other answers apparently.

Where I went wrong was misunderstanding what the namespace actually does. Anyway I had to use xmlnamespacenmanager to declare the same namespace as in the xml file. Then I had to use the namespace in the query.

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load(@"C:\deroschedule\test6.sym");
XmlNamespaceManager ns = new XmlNamespaceManager(doc.NameTable);
ns.AddNamespace("ma", "http://www.yournamespaceinfohere.com/");
var orient = doc.SelectSingleNode("//ma:attr[@name='Orientation']/@value", ns);
```

Now my next challenge is to try and read the bmp from the xml file, should be easy, right?!

Comment: If you find yourself doing a lot with XML, create a simple console app, to experiment with XML, namespaces, xpath and so on. Apologies if you've already done this or it's very obvious.

Comment: no it sounds like an excellent idea, will certainly be doing that! Thanks